# SQL for update query.

Tags: mysql, sql

*I want my sql query to stop using the query when a company have more then 4500 employees. But atm I dont get the right value when its under 4500, (price is 
45$/employee)*

```
{CASE WHEN ([company].[nremployees]* 45) <4500 
THEN 4500 
ELSE 
CASE WHEN ([company].[nremployees]* 45) > 4500 THEN
[company].[pricespecial] else
0 END END else [company].[servicebill] end}
```

Comment: Right now Im only getting the right value (4500) when its under 100 empoyess

Comment: Enclosing the database, table and column names in square brackets (`[company].[nremployees]`) is SQL Server syntax, not MySQL. MySQL uses backticks (`\`company\`.\`nremployees\``) for this purpose. [SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-reference) and [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/) are different, unrelated software products produced by different companies. Please use the correct tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are too many `END`, and you are overcomplicating it. Try with a simplified version

```
CASE
    WHEN [company].[nremployees] < 100 THEN 4500 
    WHEN [company].[nremployees] > 100 THEN [company].[pricespecial]
    ELSE [company].[servicebill] /* or 0, can't understand from your query */
END
```

Comment: It works now! This is my first time asking a question here, thank you for the fast reply.

Comment: Glad it worked! If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.